# shared_ptr polymorphism on templated type

Tags: templates, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

`std::shared_ptr` allows for polymorphism of the stored type, for instance:

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};
```

I can have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` that holds `B` objects.

But what if I want to take this a step further and make `A` a template and store `std::shared_ptr`s of different specializations of `A`. For instance:

```
template<typename T> class A {};

class Strategy {};
class StrategyOne : public Strategy {};
class StrategyTwo : public Strategy {};
```

Is it possible to have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A<Strategy>>>` that can store `StrategyOne` and `StrategyTwo` type objects at the same time?

Comment: No. `A<Strategy>`, `A<StrategyOne>` and `A<StrategyTwo>` are three distinct, unrelated classes (they don't even need to have any methods in common, thanks to specialization). A pointer to one of them (whether smart or otherwise) cannot be converted to a pointer to another.

Answer (score 0):

[Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) is exactly correct, an `A<Strategy>` has nothing in common with an `A<StrategyOne>`.

That said, in my case I realized that `A` is a trivial class, in my case a `factory`. That meant I could simply make `Strategy` inherit and specialize `A` to solve my problem. Simplified it becomes something like this:

```
template<typename T> class A {
public:
    virtual T* get() = 0;
};

class Strategy : public A<Strategy> {
public:
    virtual Strategy* get() { return new Strategy; }
};

class StrategyOne : public Strategy {
public:
    virtual StrategyOne* get() { return new StrategyOne; }
};
```

Now `Strategy` and `StrategyOne` are both `A<Strategy>` types so I can store them in a `shared_ptr<A<Strategy>`. Due to polymorphic return types, `StrategyOne`'s `get()` method can be called from `A<Strategy>` and usefully for me, I can still use `StrategyOne` to directly get a `StrategyOne *`.